# Maximum Call Stack Exceed Using Vue Js Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have common problem like other people here and i try to follow their solution but i still can't get it through. Here in my app, i need to login first then select the corporation before proceeding to the main page. I have no problem with the login, my problem is on the select corporation. I need to attach a guard that could prevent them from accessing the main page if they have not chosen a corporation. What i did is check the localstorage if the selectCorporation is empty, then i will be able to know that they have selected a corporation.

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'overview', component: Overview },

        // Authentication
        { path: '/auth/login', name: 'auth.login', component: Login, meta: { requiresVisitor: true }},

        //Select Corporation
        { path: 'select-corporation', name: 'corporations.select', component: CorporationsSelect }

        // Branches
        { path: '/branches', name: 'branches.index', component: BranchesIndex },
        { path: '/branches/create', name: 'branches.create', component: BranchesCreate },
        { path: '/branches/:id', name: 'branches.view', component: BranchesView },
        { path: '/branches/:id/edit', name: 'branches.edit', component: BranchesEdit },

    });

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

            if (localStorage.getItem('selectedCorporation') === null) {
                next({
                    path: '/select-corporation'
                });
            } else {
                next({
                    path: '/branches'
                });
            }
    });

export default router;
```

Comment: I think your guard is always redirecting to `select-corporation` even if target route is `select-corporation` itself. So it's infinite redirect loop.

Comment: @MaxSinev. yeah i believe thats the problem. So how i can fix this i already put the else condition? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your target route is not `select-corporation` to interrupt infinite redirecting loop, also "else" block causes the same behavior if corporation is selected already:

```
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('selectedCorporation') === null) {
            // checking to avoid loop
            if (to.name === 'corporations.select') return next();
            next({
                path: '/select-corporation'
            });
        }
        else {
           next();
        }
     });
```

If you want to redirect user to `branches` page after corp selected, just do it in `CorporationsSelect` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still the same error. Maximum call stack exceeded

Comment: @Joseph you missed `/` in the beginning of corporation route path, add it and try again.

Comment: I updated my answer code a little bit. You can check this jsfiddle i created  to test your issue https://jsfiddle.net/3px84r2b/ there is no error...

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. Have a great day

Comment: When i try to click other button when selectedCorporation is null, thats when the maximum call stack appears. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what should this button do? is it related to router somehow?

Comment: I mean other menus not button, sorry

Comment: `beforeEach` hook should work without any problems now. I think the problem is in another place, you can provide some code to see how this menu works.

Comment: Its alright. I shall figure this out. Can you upvote mu question too? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may add a check. if coming from and next path is not same then go for path.

```
 if (localStorage.getItem('selectedCorporation') === null) {
    if (to.redirectedFrom !== to.path) {
       next({path: '/select-corporation'});
      } 
     } else {
        next({path: '/branches' });
     }
```

it worked for me .